# Someone used my Google Analytics Tracking ID, how do I remove that traffic in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Someone used my Google Analytics Tracking ID, how do I remove that traffic in GA4?

This seemed possible with UA properties, but can't find how to do this in GA4 properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to filter out other hostname's traffic. Convoluted but still.

You can add a filter to every GA4 report. Click "Add filter" under the title of the report. This will open a right side pane. In that pane, scroll down to find "hostname" and select your own hostname (the one you want to collect traffic data from).

To make things more permanent, I'd suggest you create a new report and add this filter to it. You'll then have to do the same for every single report you want to analyse.

These reports will then disappear into the -very- hidden reports library (bottom left of the page).

I'd suggest you create a collection inside the reports library (and add these new reports to the collection) as that will allow you to find these new (filtered) reports more easily in your left side pane.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only two options to filter traffic in Google Analytics 4 are the following:

- [Developer traffic](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13296662): Filter out activity from developers who use debug
  mode.
- [Internal traffic](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10104470): Filter out users with an IP address or range
  of IP addresses.

Filtering a specific hostname can be done through Google Tag Manager. There's a built-in variable called [Page Hostname](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7182738?hl=en) which can be set as a condition for the tags trigger.